# Aligning a button to the center

Tags: html, css

I have a simple submit button. I am wanting to align it to the center. Here is my code:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onClick="Submit" align="center">
```

However, it does not work. What is the best/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">  
    <input type="submit" />  
</div>
```

Or you could use something like this. By giving the element a width and specifying `auto` for the left and right margins the element will center itself in its parent.

```
<input type="submit" style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;" />
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. You posted two different ways of accomplishing the task. One of them is correct, the other wrong. You can use `text-align: center` on the parent which is correct. But he may not want everything in the parent to be centered. Adding it just for centering would be wasteful markup. The addition of `margin: 0 auto;` to this solution is unnecessary. That is a separate method. It requires the submit button to have a `width` defined. You should correct your current answer and probably post the second solution also.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me:

```
    <input type="submit" style="margin-left: 50%">
```

If you only add margin, without the left part, it will center the submit button into the middle of your entire page, making it difficult to find and rendering your form incomplete for people who don't have the patience to find a submit button lol. margin-left centers it within the same line, so it's not further down your page than you intended. 
You can also use pixels instead of percentage if you just want to indent the submit button a bit and not all the way halfway across the page.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked using flexbox, which is in my opinion the cleanest solution.

Add a css class around the parent div / element with :

```
.parent {
display: flex;
}
```

and for the button use:

```
.button {
justify-content: center;
}
```

You should use a parent div, otherwise the button doesn't 'know' what the middle of the page / element is.

If this is not working, try :

```
#wrapper {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 50%;
```

You can adjust the percentage as needed. It seems to work for me in responsive emails.

Answer (score 0):

Add **width:100px**, **margin:50%**. 
Now the left side of the button is set to the center.
Finally add half of the **width** of the button in our case **50px**.
The middle of the button is in the center.

```
<input type='submit' style='width:100px;margin:0 50%;position:relative;left:-50px;'>
```