# How to center the submit button?

Tags: html, css

I want to center the submit button on the last div, but i can´t do it.
I try a lot of things, like margin:auto, align-left and right and others asks you make at this page, but it´s imposible for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Mi Revista</title>
    <style>

body {
    background: #7f7f7f;
}

#container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    background: #5783a0;
    height: 75px;
}

#contenido {
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: white;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width: 470px;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 300px;
}

#bordei {
    border-style: solid none;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black white;
    background: #efefef;
    margin: 0px 0px 2px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;  
}

#borded {
    border-style: solid none;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black white;
    background: #efefef;
    margin: 0px 10px 2px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;  
}

#derecha {
    float:left;
    width: 330px;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 300px;
}

#footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    clear:both;
}

div form {
    display:block
}

#acept {
    margin:auto; 
}


    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"> Mi Revista</div>
        <div id="contenido"> texto de arriba</div> 
        <div id="left">
            <div id="bordei"> borde uno</div>
            formulario izquierda
        </div>
        <div id="derecha"> 
            <div id="borded">borde derecha </div>
            Formulario derecha
            </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <form id="acept">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Aceptar"/>
            </form>
            </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wait for your awnswer, beacuse I can´t do it of any form.
Thaks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aligning a button to the center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971740/aligning-a-button-to-the-center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the text-align:center in #acept is the simplest way.
You could as well use the &ltcenter&gt tag, but is is deprecated. So the best way would be to change

```
#acept{
margin:auto;
}
```

to

```
#acept{
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `CSS` slightly as follows

```
#acept {
    width:20px;
    margin:0 auto; 
}
```

The problem was that you wasnt specifying a width for the form and due to that it was taking 100% width.And thus the `margin:0 auto` doesnt work.

I've done a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/rtyhuyLz/1/)**.Please check it..

Answer (score 2):

> Just give alignment center to footer div

```
<div id="footer" align="center">
```

Comment: that's a much better solution than specifying the width explicitly in the css. +1

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
#acept {
    margin-left:40%;
    width:10%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE Link](http://jsfiddle.net/pevvym05/)